# Difference between BaseSpider and CrawlSpider

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I have been trying to understand the concept of using BaseSpider and CrawlSpider in web scraping. I have read the [docs.](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html) But there is no mention on BaseSpider. It would be really helpful to me if someone explain the differences between **BaseSpider** and **CrawlSpider**.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`BaseSpider` is something existed before and now is *deprecated* (since [0.22](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/news.html?highlight=basespider#id12)) - use `scrapy.Spider` instead:

```
import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    # ...
```

[`scrapy.Spider`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy-spider) is the simplest spider that would, basically, visit the URLs defined in `start_urls` or returned by `start_requests()`.

Use [`CrawlSpider`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider) when you need a "crawling" behavior - extracting the links and following them:

> This is the most commonly used spider for crawling regular websites,
>   as it provides a **convenient mechanism for following links by defining
>   a set of rules**. It may not be the best suited for your particular web
>   sites or project, but it’s generic enough for several cases, so you
>   can start from it and override it as needed for more custom
>   functionality, or just implement your own spider.

Comment: Ok. That's clear a lot of things. But it would be better if you please explain the difference between BaseSpider and CrawlSpider.

Comment: Thanks, this fulfills my query. :)