# How use 2 yield in python Scrapy?

Tags: python-2.7, callback, request, scrapy, yield

i use **Scrapy** and python 2.7
i need to use 2 yield in my class, the first one for scraping the sub-cat and the second one for doing the pagination. i need something like that

```
class myClass(BaseSpider):
    cmt = 0
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         super(myClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def start_requests(self):
       start_urls = 'https://www.adresse.fr'
       yield Request(start_urls, callback=self.firstDef)

    def firstDef(self,response):
        body = response.css('body').extract_first()
        #put the body in a file
        if (self.cmt > 10) :
            url = 'https://www.theOtherAdresse.com'
            yield Request(url, callback=self.secondDef)
        print self.cmt
        self.cmt = self.cmt + 1
        yield Request(response.url, callback=self.firstDef)

    def secondDef(self,response):
       body = response.css('body').extract_first()
       #put the body in a file
       print "Finish"
```

what's wrong with my code? why i can't have 2 yields?

**UPDATE:**

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32632001/difference-between-basespider-and-crawlspider)  and i use CrawlSpider but i can't call secondDef yet.

**UPDATE**

MY CODE :

```
class Myclass(CrawlSpider):
    reload(sys)
    pageNumber = 0
    cmt = 0
    sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
    name = 'myclass'
    allowed_domains = ["amazon.fr"]
    firstPage = True
    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//div[@id="mainResults"]//h3[@class="newaps"]/a',)),
             callback='parse_page1', follow=True),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//div[@id="bottomBar"]/div[@id="pagn"]/span[@class="pagnLink"]/a',)),
             follow=True),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=(
            '//div[@class="s-item-container"]//a[@class="a-link-normal s-access-detail-page a-text-normal"]',)),
            callback='parse_page1', follow=True),
    ]
    arrayCategories = []
    pageCrawled = []
    fileNumbers = 0
    first = 0
    start_urls = ['https://www.amazon.fr/s/ref=sr_nr_p_6_0?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A197861031%2Cn%3A!197862031%2Cn%3A212130031%2Cn%3A3008171031%2Cp_76%3A211708031%2Cp_6%3AA1X6FK5RDHNB96&bbn=3008171031&ie=UTF8&qid=1463074601&rnid=211045031'
                    ,'https://www.amazon.fr/s/ref=sr_nr_p_6_0?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A197861031%2Cn%3A!197862031%2Cn%3A212130031%2Cn%3A3008171031%2Cp_76%3A211708031%2Cp_6%3AA1X6FK5RDHNB96&bbn=3008171031&ie=UTF8&qid=1463074601&rnid=211045031',
                    'https://www.amazon.fr/s/ref=sr_nr_n_1/275-0316831-3563928?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A197861031%2Cn%3A%21197862031%2Cn%3A212130031%2Cn%3A3008171031%2Cp_76%3A211708031%2Cp_6%3AA1X6FK5RDHNB96%2Cn%3A212136031&bbn=3008171031&ie=UTF8&qid=1463075247&rnid=3008171031',
                    ]
    def __init__(self, idcrawl=None, iddrive=None, idrobot=None, proxy=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Myclass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def start_requests(self):
        for i in range (0, len(self.start_urls)):
            yield Request(self.start_urls[i], callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        yield Request(response.url, callback = self.parse_produit)
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        try:
            nextPageLink = hxs.select("//a[@id='pagnNextLink']/@href").extract()[0]
            nextPageLink = urlparse.urljoin(response.url, nextPageLink)
            self.log('\nGoing to next search page: ' + nextPageLink + '\n', log.DEBUG)
            yield Request(nextPageLink, callback=self.parse)
        except:
            self.log('Whole category parsed: ', log.DEBUG)

    def parse_produit(self,response):
        print self.pageNumber
        body = response.css('body').extract_first()
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        body = response.css('body').extract_first()
        f = io.open('./amazon/page%s' % str(self.pageNumber), 'w+', encoding='utf-8')
        f.write(body)
        f.close()
        self.pageNumber = self.pageNumber + 1
```

Comment: what's the error you are getting?

Comment: Isn't basespider deprecated?

Comment: @eLRuLL i have no error, but i can't call secondDef, i mean o have never "Finish"

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida No i tried by CrawlSpider too

Comment: In firstDef, in `if self.cmt > 10`, self.cmt is always 0 so your Request to firstDef will never be called.

Comment: @Steve excuse me, i forgot to add this, no in my code i had this. i edited my question

Comment: I thought that was too easy! Do you see the value of cmt that's printed being >= 11?

Comment: @steve when i arrive the moment of execution of secondDef, the program is finished. i just want to know how can i use 2 yield in my code

Comment: Using two yields isn't a problem. I'm trying to find out if the Request with secondDef is ever called and that depends on the value of self.cmt which you are printing out. When you run the spider do you ever see values of self.cmt printed that are greater than 10? Alternatively you could add a print statement immediately after that Request  to show that the body of the if statement is being executed.

Comment: it's just a example, if you give an example that you use 2 yield who execute both of them, i  will have my answer

Comment: @parik Did you ever solve your problem?

Comment: @Steve  now i use Selenium, but i think that the problem was overwriting on Parse, but i'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that having two yields is your problem, I think it's the `if self.cmt > 10` statement which is why I asked if you ever see self.cmt values greater than 10. Here's a quick demo of having two yelds in one method.

```
def example():
    for i in range(1,10):
        yield i
        yield i * i


for e in example():
    print e
```

and this is its output:
1
1
2
4
3
9
4
16
 which is what you would expect.

**One other possibility** is that scrapy has a duplicate URL filter. If you add `, dont_filter = True` to your Request then the filter will be disabled. See the docs [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-objects)

And finally, inherit your spider from scrapy.Spider

```
class myClass(scrapy.Spider)
```

**Update:** Do you have any evidence at all that firstDef() is being called more than once, because it doesn't look like it is??

Comment: What i need to know is how to use 2 yield with 2 callback in 2 def different, maybe my exemple is not good

Comment: for Down vote it wasn't me, your answe doesn't help me, i think that my problem is the method Parse in Scrapy. anyway thanks for answer

Comment: Now Worries Parik. I was only trying to say that two yields in one routine should work without any problems and then go on to try and diagnose what was happening with your code. Ah well.

Comment: I found your example @Steve useful for me